# how to put embedded document into an embedded document?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

I have a form that has a category model and and embeded docuement called "FieldModule" and this has embedded document called "SubFieldModule"

For example

```
class Category

  include MongoMapper::Document  
  key :name, String 
  many :field_modules
end

class FieldModule

  include MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument  
  key :name, String 
  many :sub_field_modules  
end

class SubFieldModule

  include MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument
  key :name, String  
end
```

In my controller i edit action i have :

```
@category = Category.find(params[:id])

3.times do
  @category.field_modules << FieldModule.new()
end
```

To set up 3 FieldModules for the category.

I want to be able to do the same for each FieldModules SubFieldModules like so

```
@category.field_modules.each do |mf| 
  mf << SubFieldModule.new()
end
```

but it doesnt work.

i get error:

```
NoMethodError in Sub categoriesController#edit

undefined method `<<' for #<FieldModule name: nil, _id: $oid4c2b9f594248ce19f000011b>
```

Anyone help me out on this ?  as i then need to take it one level deeper doing the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@cat = Category.new(:name => "Blah")

3.times do
  @cat.field_modules << FieldModule.new()
end

@cat.field_modules.each do |mf|
  mf.sub_field_modules << SubFieldModule.new()
end
```

Comment: Does this actually work? I seem to be having problems either way when embedding an EmbeddedDocument into another EmbeddedDocument.